# Splitting values in different columns in R

Tags: r, split, strsplit

One of the column in my dataset contains values like

```
utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1234567&utm_term=brand%20&utm_content=Brand&gclid=ERtyuiipotf_YTj
```

How should I split this in different columns with its values in R?

```
utm_source utm_medium  utm_campaign utm_brand  utm_content
  google      cpc          1234567   brand%20     Brand
```

`dput(column)` gives below output

```
structure(list("null", "gclid=ertyyhglkdl-kjkY", 
    "utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1234556&utm_term=brand%20shirts&utm_content=Brand&gclid=jhajsgjdgd_ajs", 
    "utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1674814043&utm_term=brand%20shirts&utm_content=Brand&gclid=KvgMsEAAYASAAEgLq6vD_BwE", 
    "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", 
    "null", "null", "utm_source=fb&utm_medium=ctw&utm_campaign=Shirt_rem&utm_content=CasciaShirt"), class = c("extracted", 
"list"))
```

Comment: Check out `separate` in `dplyr`

Comment: Example @AmadouKone?..suppose my dataset is Mydata and column name is col1 and I want it to be split in different columns as utm_source, utm_campaign, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the expected output. Below might be a base R option for your goal

```
Reduce(
  function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE),
  lapply(
    column,
    function(x) {
      u <- unlist(strsplit(x, "&"))
      setNames(data.frame(as.list(gsub(".*=", "", u))), gsub("=.*", "", u))
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  utm_source utm_medium utm_campaign utm_content null                    gclid
1         fb        ctw    Shirt_rem CasciaShirt <NA>                     <NA>
2     google        cpc      1234556       Brand <NA>           jhajsgjdgd_ajs
3     google        cpc   1674814043       Brand <NA> KvgMsEAAYASAAEgLq6vD_BwE
4       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>        <NA> null         ertyyhglkdl-kjkY
        utm_term
1           <NA>
2 brand%20shirts
3 brand%20shirts
4           <NA>
```

---

**Update**

If you want to preserve all the data even if it is `null`, you can try the code below

```
Reduce(
  function(x, y) {
    if (all(is.na(x)) | all(is.na(y))) {
      return(rbind(x, y))
    }
    dplyr::full_join(x, y)
  },
  lapply(
    column,
    function(x) {
      if (x == "null") {
        return(NA)
      }
      u <- unlist(strsplit(x, "&"))
      setNames(data.frame(as.list(gsub(".*=", "", u))), gsub("=.*", "", u))
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
                      gclid utm_source utm_medium utm_campaign       utm_term
1                      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
2          ertyyhglkdl-kjkY       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
3            jhajsgjdgd_ajs     google        cpc      1234556 brand%20shirts
4  KvgMsEAAYASAAEgLq6vD_BwE     google        cpc   1674814043 brand%20shirts
5                      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
6                      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
7                      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
8                      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
9                      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
10                     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
11                     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
12                     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
13                     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
14                     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>
15                     <NA>         fb        ctw    Shirt_rem           <NA>
   utm_content
1         <NA>
2         <NA>
3        Brand
4        Brand
5         <NA>
6         <NA>
7         <NA>
8         <NA>
9         <NA>
10        <NA>
11        <NA>
12        <NA>
13        <NA>
14        <NA>
15 CasciaShirt
```

Comment: This is working @ThomasIsCoding..but it gives me only those columns with values..how do I extract complete results even if there are null values, I want them in the data

Answer (score 0):

With the OP's updated example as a `list`, we loop over the `list`, `if` the elements are not `"null"`, then create a `tibble`, split the column at `&` with `separate_rows` and then split that column into multiple columns (`separate`), create a tibble from the named vector (`deframe`) with `as_tibble_row`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(lst1, ~ if(.x != "null") tibble(col1 = .x) %>% 
             separate_rows(col1, sep="&") %>% 
             separate(col1, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep="\\=") %>%
             deframe %>% 
             as_tibble_row())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  gclid                    utm_source utm_medium utm_campaign utm_term       utm_content
#  <chr>                    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>          <chr>      
#1 ertyyhglkdl-kjkY         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>       
#2 jhajsgjdgd_ajs           google     cpc        1234556      brand%20shirts Brand      
#3 KvgMsEAAYASAAEgLq6vD_BwE google     cpc        1674814043   brand%20shirts Brand      
#4 <NA>                     fb         ctw        Shirt_rem    <NA>           CasciaShirt
```

---

Or instead of doing this in a loop, we can convert the `list` to a column in `data.frame`, do this once and pivot to wide format

```
library(data.table)
keep(lst1, ~ .x != "null") %>%
     flatten_chr %>% 
     tibble(col1 = .) %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
     separate_rows(col1, sep='&') %>% 
     separate(col1, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep="\\=") %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2) %>% 
     select(-rn)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  gclid                    utm_source utm_medium utm_campaign utm_term       utm_content
#  <chr>                    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>          <chr>      
#1 ertyyhglkdl-kjkY         <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>           <NA>       
#2 jhajsgjdgd_ajs           google     cpc        1234556      brand%20shirts Brand      
#3 KvgMsEAAYASAAEgLq6vD_BwE google     cpc        1674814043   brand%20shirts Brand      
#4 <NA>                     fb         ctw        Shirt_rem    <NA>           CasciaShirt
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- structure(list("null", "gclid=ertyyhglkdl-kjkY", "utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1234556&utm_term=brand%20shirts&utm_content=Brand&gclid=jhajsgjdgd_ajs", 
    "utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1674814043&utm_term=brand%20shirts&utm_content=Brand&gclid=KvgMsEAAYASAAEgLq6vD_BwE", 
    "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", 
    "null", "null", "utm_source=fb&utm_medium=ctw&utm_campaign=Shirt_rem&utm_content=CasciaShirt"), class = c("extracted", 
"list"))
```

Comment: Sorry. I am getting this error could not find function "separate_rows"

Comment: Yes used it. Now getting this Error in UseMethod("separate_rows_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_rows_' applied to an object of class "list"                                                                      Class of the column I am considering is "extracted" "list"

Comment: Added in the question itself

Comment: So any solution @akrun?

Comment: I have a list..Prior to this I used Mydata$query=ex_between(Mydata$"Ref URL", "query_string=", "|")                                                                           and the column that I am considering for this question is query which is obtained from the above code

Comment: @anonymus in that `list`, there are some entires "null" and some have `" "gclid=ertyyhglkdl-kjkY"`. can you show the expected output for that.  Is it based on the whole list.  What will be rows?

Comment: My final output should have columns utm_source, utm_campaign, utm_medium..other than this anything like gclid or null values are not required...I want information in every row containing these columns..if it is not present then it can be blank or null

Comment: Hi I got the result using smaller dataset, but for large dataset..the result is incomplete. Getting this error --> arguments imply differing number of rows: 616, 311